# Given an array, find whether there are 2 numbers whose difference is c

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution to this problem and wondering whether there is a better solution. If we were trying to find 2 numbers, whose sum is c, then i know that there is an O(nlogn) solution. (given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334981/find-pair-of-numbers-in-array-that-add-to-given-sum)) I try the similar approach here: i first sort the array using mergesort in O(nlogn) time, then i start from both ends of the array, and look at their differences. If this is equal to c, then we are done. If difference is bigger than c, then i decrease the rightmost index by 1, but i think this is wrong, we cannot know whether we have do decrease the rightmost index or we have to increase the leftmost index. Am i right? Can we solve this problem in a better time complexity?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They key is that once the array is sorted, binary search is only `O(logn)`.

For each number `x` in the array, test whether `x-c` is in the array via binary search. This is still `O(nlogn)`.

If you want to be fancy, you can do it by only iterating twice through the array, but the complexity is dominated by the sorting step anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My Approach, using hash and `no need for pre-sorting`, It depends on the hash implementation, In the Best Case it can be done in O(n), In the worst case O(nlogn),

```
arr[] = { ... }
hash[] // maps Integer to Boolean
for e in arr:
    hash[e] = true
    if hash[e+c] == true Or hash[e-c] == true:
        return true
return false
```

Iterating over the array, for each element `e` do:

- map `e` to true in the hash
- if there are element with difference of `c` to the current element, then Bingo :D

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Worst case is Omega(n^2), but +1 all the same, for a practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array which, takes O(n log n) time.  Then you can create a second array by replacing each member x in the first with c - x, and then reversing. Then, you can see if the two arrays have an element in commonwhich takes two traversals for O(n) each.