# Algorithm's Running Time Optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time, while-loop, big-o

I'm trying to find a way to optimize my algorithm such that the running time is O(n²) (Big O Notation).

The input is an array with n elements, of only positive and negative integers. We can assume that the array is already sorted.

I have to determine: for each r (element of the array), whether r = s + t, where s and t are also elements of the array, and can be the same (s == t), or also zero.

I tried to reduce the number of elements I have to check by checking if the current number is positive or negative, but the running time is still too long. The problem is that I'm using 3 while loops which already means a running time of O(n³) for the worst case.

Here is my code:

```
public static void Checker(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> testlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        int current = array[i];
        if (attached(current, array)) {
            testlist.add(current);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

public static boolean attached(int current, int[] array) {
    boolean result = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < array.length && !result) {
        int number1 = array[i];
        int j = 0;
        while (j < array.length && !result) {
            int number2 = array[j];
            if (number1 + number2 == current) {
                result = true;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, add all elements from array to HashSet, then iterate over s and t and check if s + t is presented in your set.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting as highlighting, it makes things very hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start sorting the array `O(nlogn)` (if not), then for each element in the array you can check if there are two elements that the sum is equals to the number in `O(n²)`.

The code is in **C#**:

```
public static bool Solve(int[] arr)
{
    Array.Sort(arr);    //If not already sorted

    foreach (var num in arr)
        if (!FindTwoThatSumN(arr, num))
            return false;

    return true;
}

public static bool FindTwoThatSumN(int[] arr, int num)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = arr.Length - 1;

    while (true)
    {
        if (min == max) break;

        int sum = arr[min] + arr[max];

        if (sum < num) min++;
        if (sum > num) max--;
        if (sum == num) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The idea to check if there are two numbers in an array (must be sorted) that sum a specific value is start from the minimum (`min = 0`) and the maximum (`max = arr.Length`), then in each iteration:

- If the sum is lower than the number, increase `min` index.
- If the sum is greater than the number, decrease `max` index.
- If the sum is equals to the number, then you find a solution.
- If `min` index reach `max` then there are no solution.

You can refer to this [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8334981/5178207) for more details and proof.

Time complexity for overall solution is `O(n²)`:

- Sort the array: `O(nlogn)`.
- Iterate over the sorted array: `O(n)`.
- Find two numbers that sum the value: `O(n)`.

So, is `O(n²)` due the nested calls to `FindTwoThatSumN`.

If you want you can pass the index instead of the number to `FindTwoThatSumN` method to avoid with an additional check use the number itself as part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. calculate all the possible sums of s+t and put the results in a set **=>** O(n<sup>2</sup>)
2. iterate over each r and check if there is a sum that matches r **=>** O(n) since `set.contains` runs in constant time.