# Print pairs of values that are in a linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

This is my code for creating a linked list:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_element {
    int inf;
    struct list_element *next;
} List;

List *create() {
    List *p, *punt;
    int x = 1;/*Random number but different from 0*/
    p = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    printf("\nFirst value: ");
    scanf("%d", &p->inf);
    punt = p;

    while (1) {/*Till x different from 0*/
        printf("\nNext value: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x == 0)
            break;
        punt->next = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
        punt = punt->next;
        punt->inf = x;
    }
    punt->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

int main(void) {
    List *a;
    a = create();
}
```

Suppose the following values to be sent in input(scanf):

> 10 20 30 40 50 15 35

I need to create a void function which sends to stdout the list of pairs of numbers whose sum is 50, so in this case the output will be

> 10 40
>
> 20 30
>
> 15 35

To do this I used two different functions:
In the first I copied the the value of the linked list in an array of int and in the second function, with a backtracking algorithm (performed on the array just created) I found the solutions.
This is my solution:

```
void BackTrack(int n, int s, int x[7], int z[7], int partial, int max, int check) {
    if (n == s) {
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (z[i] != 0 && check == 2 && partial == max) {
                printf("%d ", z[i]);
                y++;
            }
        }
        if(y != 0)
            printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    z[s] = 0;
    BackTrack(n, s + 1, x, z, partial, max, check);

    if (x[s] + partial <= max) {
        z[s] = x[s];
        partial += x[s];
        check++;
        BackTrack(n, s + 1, x, z, partial, max, check);
    }
}

void ARRAY(List *p) {
    int *x = NULL;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; p != NULL; i++){
        x = realloc(x, sizeof(int) * (i + 1));
        x[i] = p->inf;
        p = p->next;
    }
    int *z = malloc(sizeof(int) * i);
    BackTrack(i, 0, x, z, 0, 50, 0);
}
```

But I wanna know if there is a way to do this without using before an array conversation as I did? So to fint directly the couples on the linked list. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design an algorithm to find all pairs of integers within an array which sum to a specified value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494130/design-an-algorithm-to-find-all-pairs-of-integers-within-an-array-which-sum-to-a)

Comment: @Tempux not really, i do not want to find pairs in the array (because I already proposed here above my solution with that method), i wanted to know if there is a way to do the same thing but on a linked list

Comment: Can the list  be changed  destructive ?

Comment: `p = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));` <-- please don't cast the return of `malloc` & co. It's required in C++, but considered harmful in C

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Ok thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void FindPairs(List *list, int sum) {

  struct list_element *i, *j;

  for (i = list; i; i = i->next) {
    if (i->inf > sum)
      continue;
    for (j = i->next; j; j = j->next) {
      if (i->inf + j->inf == sum)
        printf("%d %d\n", i->inf, j->inf);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG, I never thought to use a for loop in this way. Nice

Answer (score 0):

1. Simple method would be using 2 for loops over the list and check for required sum, Complexity - O(n^2).
2. Use hashmap, store first value in hash map, now from 2nd value, if sum-2ndValue exist in hashmap, your solution, else insert in hashmap. - Time Complexity - O(n), Space Complexity - O(n).

Answer (score -1):

I you have the space, copy all values in a sorted data structure like a sorted list. Than you can simultan iterate from both sides and find the pairs this way.

Speed:

- create the sorted list: **O(n log n)**
- iterate to find the pairs: **O(n)**

---

if you have not enough space, you need to iterate through the linked list very often.

**Pseudocode:**

```
nodeLeft=fistNodeInList
while(nodeLeft.hasNext)
  nodeRight=nodeLeft
  while(nodeRight.hasNext)
    nodeRight= nodeRight.next
    if(nodeRight.value+nodeLeft.value= sum
      print odeRight.value nodeLeft.value
  nodeLeft=nodeLeft.next
```

This has **O(n²)** speed