# Goldbach's Conjecture - Find the number of ways an even number can be written as the sum of two primes

Tags: python, math

I want to know the number of ways that a given positive even number can be written as the sum of two primes.

At the moment, I have this code:

```
n = int(input(">"))
def genprimes(n):#generate primes from 2 to n
    primes = []
    for i in range(2,n):
        prime = True
        for a in range(2,i):
            if i % a == 0:
                prime = False
        if prime == True:
            primes.append(i)
    return primes

pairs = []
primes = genprimes(n)

for prime1 in primes:
    for prime2 in primes:
        if prime1 + prime2 == n and [prime1,prime2] not in pairs and [prime2,prime1] not in pairs:
            pairs.append([prime1,prime2])
print(len(pairs))
```

It works, but it becomes a little slow when `n` goes above `10,000` ish. Can anyone think of a more efficient way to find this value, so that it yields quick results for high values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two slow algorithms.

To get your list of primes, you separately check each number for prime-hood. The fastest way get a list of primes is to use a pre-built list of primes--that is what I do for such problems. The list of primes up to 2**16 (65,536) takes only 6542 integers and I store that list in a module. You may prefer to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) which is generally recognized as the fastest way to get such a list from scratch.

You then try each pair of primes to see if they add to your target number. It would be much faster to, for each prime `p`, see if `n-p` is also prime. You could check `n-p` with a binary search, as @Shubham suggests, but it would probably be faster to have two indices, one regularly going up and yielding `p` and the other going down as needed checking for `n-p`. It might be quickest to copy your prime list to a set and use that to check if `n-p` is in the list. These last two techniques are of order `n`, but for numbers only up to 10,000 the overhead may affect which technique is best. And yes, for such problems 10,000 is not very large. Finally, if memory is not a concern, @BoulderKeith points out that you could leave the prime list as a list of Booleans (True/False) and very quickly check if `n-p` is prime--this is the fastest, if most memory-consuming, technique of all.

Comment: I don't want to add another answer myself, but here's some working code:  https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/c471b24c9a4717010681f0c5e33d6be9

Answer (score 2):

This can be done efficiently by optimizing both part of your program.

First, we can optimize the `genprimes()` by generating primes using Sieve of Eratosthenes which can generate prime upto `n` in `O(nlog(log(n))`.

After that, once we have the list of primes, we can do the following:

- Iterate through the prime list and select a prime, say `p1`.
- Using Binary Search check whether `n-p1` also exist in the prime list.

If `p = number of primes till n`

then the complexity of this part will be `O(plog(p))`.

As [@PaulHankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/paul-hankin) suggested, from [@SrujanKumarGulla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13828973/3160529)'s answer, we can build up a `O(p)` solution once we have the prime list.

Implementation of second part (the first part is standard [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)):

```
# prime list is assumed to be sorted. It will be if it's generated
# using Sieve of Eratosthenes

def solutions(n, prime_list):
    low = 0, high = len(prime_list)-1
    sol = []
    while low < high:
        temp = prime_list[low] + prime_list[high]
        if temp == n:
            sol.append((prime_list[low], prime_list[high], ))
        elif temp < n:
            low += 1
        else:
            high -= 1

    return len(sol)
```

Comment: Given the (sorted) list of primes < n it's quite easy to find all pairs that sum to n in O(p) time -- see for example SK Gulla's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494130/design-an-algorithm-to-find-all-pairs-of-integers-within-an-array-which-sum-to-a .

Comment: @PaulHankin I checked the answer, but it states that once, `n` = the sum of values at indexes `i` and `j`, we should return. Wouldn't it find just a single possibility instead of all the possibilities? And I thought of suggesting the solution using `bitmap` (which would also be `O(p)`)but it will only work if the maximum number is around `10^7`. The HasMap solution should probably be the best one in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that solution gives just one pair as written, but it's almost trivial to change it to generate all solutions -- just replace the "return" with an "append to a list of solutions".

Comment: @PaulHankin Oh yes. Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

If memory is not an issue, you can optimize speed even more by:

1) Building an array from 2..n with array[i]=true if i is prime.  (Sieve of Eratosthenes or something fancier can be used.)

2) For all 2 <= i < n/2 see if both array[i] and array[n-i] are both true. If so, then i and n-i are a pair.  (Setting the upper limit of i to n/2 means you don't have to remove duplicates either.)

The entire algorithm is O(n log n). (O(n log n) to build the primes; O(n) to find pairs.)

I did this in C# rather than Python, but was able to find all pairs with n = 100,000,000 in 10 seconds.

Comment: I forgot about keeping the Sieve of Eratosthenes as a list of Booleans or the equivalent--that would be fastest of all. Well done! I upvoted this answer, and if you don't mind I'll refer to this technique in my answer. (I'll wait half an hour for your reply.)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Please use my response as you please.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def prim(n):
        primes = []
        for num in range(1, n + 1):     # current number check
            limit = int(num ** 0.5) + 1 # search limit
            for div in range(2, limit): # searching for divider
                if (num % div) == 0:    # divider found
                    break               # exit the inner loop
            else:                       # out of the inner loop
                primes.append(num)      # no divider found hence prime
        return(primes)

    num = int(input('Input an even number: '))
    primes = prim(num)                  # create list of primes

    for i in range(num//2 + 1):
        if num % 2 != 0:
            print(num, 'not even'); break
        if i in primes and (num - i) in primes:
            print(i, '+', num - i)
"""
Examples:
=========
Input an even number: 18
1 + 17
5 + 13
7 + 11

Input an even number: 88
5 + 83
17 + 71
29 + 59
41 + 47

Input an even number: 17
17 not even
"""
```

Comment: add some explantion to your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual solution from [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6246044/rory-daulton)'s suggestions, which uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes to efficiently generate the primes and then sees if `n-prime` is also prime.

The count of solutions for which this is true then needed to be halved and rounded up to prevent duplicates.

```
n = int(input(">"))
def genprimes(n):
    limitn = n+1
    not_prime = set()
    primes = []

    for i in range(2, limitn):
        if i in not_prime:
            continue
        for f in range(i*2, limitn, i):
            not_prime.add(f)
        primes.append(i)
    return primes

nos=0
primes = genprimes(n)

for prime in primes:
    if n-prime in primes:
        nos += 1
print(str(int((nos/2)+0.5)))
```

Comment: Your check `if n-prime in primes` is linear speed in the `primes` list so your last part is quadratic and probably unnecessarily slow. Copying `primes` to a set would probably speed things up. See the recent additions to my answer for other ideas to speed up that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

With this version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes it is possible to quickly
find the number of ways in which a even number can be written
as the sum of two primes:

```
import numpy as np
def goldbach(n):
    P5m6 =np.ones((n//6+1), dtype=bool)
    P1m6 =np.ones((n//6+1), dtype=bool)
    for i in range(1,int((n**0.5+1)/6)+1):
        if P5m6[i]:
            P5m6[6*i*i::6*i-1]=[False]
            P1m6[6*i*i-2*i::6*i-1]=[False]
        if P1m6[i]:
            P5m6[6*i*i::6*i+1]=[False]
            P1m6[6*i*i+2*i::6*i+1]=[False]

    nmod6=n%6
    if nmod6==0:
        return np.count_nonzero(P5m6[1:n//6]&P1m6[n//6-1:0:-1])
    elif nmod6==2:
        return np.count_nonzero(P1m6[1:(n-6)//12+(n//6-1)%2+1]&P1m6[n//6-1:(n-6)//12:-1])+np.count_nonzero(P5m6[n//6])
    elif nmod6==4:
        return np.count_nonzero(P5m6[1:n//12+(n//6)%2+1]&P5m6[n//6:n//12:-1])+np.count_nonzero(P1m6[n//6])
    else:
        return -1
print(goldbach(100000000))
```